# Sort list of point class based on two values C#

Tags: c#, class

I want to sort a List of the class Points in C# (See below) based first on x and then on y.

```
public class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Point(int xp, int yp)
    {
        x = xp;
        y = yp;
    }
}
```

How do you do this: I am brand new to C#, and are there any similarities to Java compare methods that implement custom comparitors for classes, and also I would like to add the compare method (int CompareTo) to the class to sort on the class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at IComparable<T> . that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you're looking for [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) and [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) - the latter is the equivalent of the `Comparator<E>` interface in Java.

If you want to add a comparison to the `Point` class itself, make `Point` implement `IComparable<Point>` (and possibly the non-generic `IComparable` interface too). If you want to implement the comparison elsewhere, make another class implement `IComparer<Point>`.

For *equality*, .NET also has `IEquatable<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>`. These are used for things like key comparisons in `Dictionary<,>`.

As a side note, I'd strongly encourage you *not* to have public fields - and you may well want to make the variables `readonly`. (Immutable types are generally easier to reason about.) You may decide to make `Point` a `struct` too, rather than a `class`.

Comment: I think `IEquatable<T>` is more general purpose which I can use for equality check anytime, whereas `IEqualityComparer<T>` is mostly used in `IDictionary<T>` for key checks and collisions etc.

Comment: @DarthVader: No, not really. The difference is simply meant to be whether an object is in charge of comparing *itself* to another item, or whether a separate object can compare *two other objects* with each other... the same as `IComparable` and `IComparer`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var points = new List<Point>() { new Point(1,3), new Point(1,4), new Point(1,2) };
var sortedPoints = points.OrderBy(point => point.x).ThenBy(point => point.y);
```

Comment: `List(of Point)` does not compile in C#.  I think you meant `List<Point>`

Comment: @BrianRogers Lol. I do a lot of switching between VB and C# at work, I always do this. Suprised I didn't forget my semicolons too.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `IComparable` interface and implement its

```
public int CompareTo( object obj )
```

in this methode you can write the logic to compare two objects for example:

```
if (objectA.x > objectB.x)
  return 1
else if (objectA.x < objectB.x)
  return -1
else // compare y in both objects
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface you want to implement in C# is [IComparable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx), which acts like Java's Comparable.  Your code then becomes

```
public class Point : IComparable<Point>
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
    }

    public Point(int xp, int yp)
    {
        x = xp;
        y = yp;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Point other)
    {
        // Custom comparison here
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the public fields into private fields, and changed the public-facing interface into [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This is more idiomatic C# - public fields are frowned upon in both Java and C#.